# Split polygon with West East direction with equal area in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, splitting, postgis-2.3, equal-area

This code splits into NS direction but I need to split with WE direction (horizontally):

```
WITH foo AS (
SELECT id,name,geom, blade
FROM admin4
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT ST_xMin(geom) + (ST_xMax(geom) - ST_xMin(geom)) / 2 ) AS axis(x)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakeLine(
ST_MakePoint(axis.x, ST_yMin(geom)),
ST_MakePoint(axis.x, ST_yMax(geom))
) AS blade where id<5
)
SELECT id,name,geom,    blade,   ST_Split(geom, st_Setsrid(blade,4326)) FROM foo;
```

Comment: The assumption that midpoint division will result in equal areas is not generally applicable. Even if you alter the line orientation, you might not achieve your goal

Answer (score 2):

There is no area involved in your query. As it is, it finds the mid point of the geometry extent and draws a vertical line.

Here it is for an horizontal line:

```sql
WITH foo AS (
 SELECT id,name,geom, blade
 FROM admin4
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT ST_yMin(geom) + (ST_yMax(geom) - ST_yMin(geom)) / 2 ) AS axis(y)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakeLine(
    ST_MakePoint(ST_xMin(geom),axis.y),
    ST_MakePoint(ST_xMax(geom),axis.y)
  ) AS blade where id<5
)
SELECT id,name,geom,    blade,   ST_Split(geom, st_Setsrid(blade,4326)) FROM foo;
```

The output, as in the OP, will be for each row a geometry collection containing the two 1/2 polygons. Here is an example:

```sql
WITH admin4(id,name,geom) as (
    values (1,'one',st_Setsrid('polygon((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))'::geometry,4326)),
     (2,'two',st_Setsrid('polygon((10 10,10 11,11 11,11 10,10 10))'::geometry,4326))
    ),
foo AS (
 SELECT id,name,geom, blade
 FROM admin4
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT ST_yMin(geom) + (ST_yMax(geom) - ST_yMin(geom)) / 2 ) AS axis(y)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakeLine(
    ST_MakePoint(ST_xMin(geom),axis.y),
    ST_MakePoint(ST_xMax(geom),axis.y)
  ) AS blade where id<5
)
SELECT id,name,--geom,    blade,   
    st_asText(ST_Split(geom, st_Setsrid(blade,4326)) )
FROM foo;
 id | name |                                                    st_astext                                               
----+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | one  | GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((0 0,0 0.5,1 0.5,1 0,0 0)),POLYGON((0 0.5,0 1,1 1,1 0.5,0 0.5)))
  2 | two  | GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((10 10,10 10.5,11 10.5,11 10,10 10)),POLYGON((10 10.5,10 11,11 11,11 10.5,10 10.5)))
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Are you sure that by repeating the failed OP design, the result posted in your response should work correctly?

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko The title and the content of the question are different. This answer addresses the question as stated in OP content, doesn't it?

Comment: I think the execution of the SQL script will not result in the polygon being split into two separate parts...

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko from a quick test it seems to work, generating for each source row a geometry collection containing the two 1/2 polygons

Comment: To be sure, try splitting the result with ST_Dump()...

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko I have included a sample... looks fine again :-)

Comment: It's OK, thanks for the clarification, in QGIS the type GEOMETRYCOLLECTION appears as a type without geometry :-)...